# Run Windows Task from Python file/script

Tags: python, windows, scripting, windows-task-scheduler

I was checking but cant find it. Is there any way to trigger Windows Task, in Windows Task Scheduler from Python. It just needs to trigger a specific task from Python file/script nothin more.

Comment: Yes, you can run `Start-ScheduledTask` from python subprocess

Comment: The complete answer would be nice xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `subprocess` module:

```py
import subprocess

task_name = "MyTask"
subprocess.run(["schtasks", "/run", "/tn", task_name])
```

- `"schtasks"` is the Windows command line utility to manage Task Scheduler
- `"/run"` is the command to run a task
- `"/tn"` specifies the task name.

(you might need to run your Python script with administrative privileges for this to work, depending on the task settings)

---

Option 2:

I've never tried it before, but [pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) looks pretty good, if you want a direct API.